# Browser downloads fail - Insufficient space in /tmp

Tags: centos, filesystems, firefox, tmpfs, tmp

I have a virtual machine (CentOS) that was pre-configured (I didn't partition them) and I have some of my work on it.

When I got access to the VM, it had very less storage space, and it isn't configured with LVM. I thus extended the hard drive in VMWare settings and created a new partition (sda3) and mounted it under a new directory in /home/user

I want to use Firefox or any other browser to download a few files into the system over the internet, but since the VM was pre-configured and didn't come with a lot of space, /tmp has run out of space.

Here's the message firefox gives me: /tmp/mozilla_user0/abc.gz.part could not be saved because the source file could not be read. Try again or contact the server administrator.

I'm assuming this is due to low space on the system. How do I resolve this? The new partition sda3 is mounted to /home/user/extend as an ext4 rw partition.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 45 root root 4096 Jul  6 20:30 /tmp

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        33G   32G   53M 100% /
tmpfs           764M   72K  764M   1% /dev/shm
```

Comment: You might want to change the title, it is somehow misleading.

Comment: Does it seem ok now?

Comment: Result of `ls -ld /tmp` please. And also `df -h`

Comment: I've added the outputs as you asked!

Comment: "_The new partition sda3 is mounted to /home/user/extend as an ext4 rw partition_" are you sure? It didn't show in your `df -h` output

Comment: I don't mount it all the time, some of my scripts take care of that. I haven't added it to fstab. Only some part of the toolflow requires the files there to be loaded into memory and they are pretty big in size. Can that cause an issue here?